# Log4j property in Jetty-9 logging framework

Tags: log4j, jetty, jetty-9

I am switching from jetty-7.6 to jetty-9.2.1. I am facing a issue where jetty server logs are not coming into the log file.

**Previously with jetty-7.6:**
I was running the server with: 
`"--ini OPTIONS=Server,jsp,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,annotations"` and setting the `property : ("log4j.configuration", "/log4j/log4j.properties")`

**Now with the new version jetty-9.2.1:**
I am running the jetty server with module option as:
`"--module=server,jsp,deploy,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,annotations"` and also setting the same property for `log4j : ("log4j.configuration", "/log4j/log4j.properties")`

But I am not able to get jetty logs.

Is there anything I am missing or some configuration changes with new version ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Did someone get a chance to look at this ?